# Check for errors in HTTP call and continue to next step in Karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to validate the booking flow. create, fetch, update and cancel bookings are present in the workflow. The booking is created successfully and if any of the steps got a failure, then I need to cancel the booking. Is there any way to add a step after failing to cancel the booking, if there is a failure in any step?

I have tried with this:

- def result = responseStatus == 404 ? {} : karate.call('delete-user.feature')

it will be applicable to only one statement. I need to apply this to all the assertion statements.